# What is the difference between findAllBy and readAllBy?

Tags: spring-data

I am trying to fix this issue [Spring Data Neo4j 4 : findByPropertyIsNull is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34317586/spring-data-neo4j-4-findbypropertyisnull-is-not-working)

Reading [spring-data-docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.query-methods)

I want to be sure that the syntax findAllByPropertyIsNull is the right synatx

So What is the difference between findAllByProperty... and readAllByProperty... ?